# TCP Socket server node js freezes

Tags: node.js, multithreading, sockets, socket.io, fork

I have a TCP socket server written in node js. The server is listening to data from about 150 GPS tracker devices and then inserting data into the database in realtime. The problem is that My server was working great when the devices were less But now as the gps tracker devices increases my server sometimes freezes meaning it does not insert the data into my database or do any function. When I check from the terminal it displays the server is running. This is the basic code which I am using. Please let me know if there is a better way to handle multithreading processing in node.

```
var net = require('net');
const cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;
    if (cluster.isMaster) {
        // Fork workers.
        for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs; i++) {
            cluster.fork();
        }

        cluster.on('death', function(worker) {
            console.log('worker ' + worker.pid + ' died');
            cluster.fork();
        });
    } else {
        net.createServer(function(socket) {
            console.log('received connection...');

            socket.on("error", function(err) {
                console.log("socket error: ")
                console.log(err.stack);
                socket.destroy();
            });
            socket.on('data', function(data) {


                console.log(data.toString());
    });
    }
```

Comment: What are you actually doing with the incoming data (show code please)?  That seems more likely to be the place you would have a problem.

Comment: What is the request frequency from these gps devices ? And it might be more sensible to assign the a few threads to do just background work and keep 1 or 2 for request handling. Because 150 devices is not much , even with a extremely fast data update frequency.

Comment: @khan hello khan each device gives data in every 10 second

Comment: @jfriend00 Well the code consist of in 1000 lines so you won't understand the code.

Comment: Well, I think that's likely where the problem is so I don't know what you expect us to do when you won't show us any of that code.  You probably have a concurrency issue or a resource leak.  FYI, 1000 lines is no big deal and you'd be surprised what problems we can find in code we've never seen before.  But, part of your job at writing a good question here is making sure we have enough information to actually help you.

Comment: @jfriend00 is quite likely  right. Do you stop getting data from all devices or just a few?

Comment: @khan sometimes from all the devices and sometimes few

Comment: Do you need to restart the server before you start getting data again ? There is a slight chance that issue might be in the network on the client side. Since TCP is reliable and it does ensures in order delivery of packets on a single connection but slow networks can cause significant delays. It might be the case that something on the client side is causing the issue.

Comment: @khan yes I have to restart the server. on the client side you mean 150 client devices?